# How deal with Option<Ref<T>> and Option<&T>

Tags: rust, reference, polymorphism

In the example we assume that we have two codes that has their perimeter and tested individually.

The **code 1** return the type `Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>`
and **code 2** that have to consume `&T`.

I have an issues with the following example [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28304563d0650bce909bfd33d74532d9).

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// Code 2
fn action(data_1: Option<&i32>, data_2: Option<&i32>) {
    println!("data_1:{:?}, data_2:{:?}", data_1, data_2);
}

fn main() {
    // Code 1
    let data_1 = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(2)));
    let data_2 = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(5)));

    let ref_data_1 = data_1.as_ref().map(|r| r.borrow());
    let ref_data_2 = data_2.as_ref().map(|r| r.borrow());

    action(ref_data_1, ref_data_2); // Error: mismatched types
}
```

The example fail because of mismatch types between `Ref<T>` is found and `&T` is expected.
My only way that I have founded is to change `Option<&i32>` to `Option<Ref<i32>>` but that break the interface of **code 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `action` function to accept *either* `Option<&i32>` or `Option<Ref<i32>>` by using a generic argument with a `Deref<Target = i32>` bound, which both of those types satisfy:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

fn action<T>(data_1: Option<T>, data_2: Option<T>)
where
    T: Deref<Target = i32>,
{
    println!("data_1:{:?}, data_2:{:?}", data_1.as_deref(), data_2.as_deref());
}
```

---

If you can't or don't want to change the signature of `action`, then you can call `as_deref()` on the arguments when you pass them in:

```
action(ref_data_1.as_deref(), ref_data_2.as_deref());
```

Comment: I feel like either `AsRef` or `Borrow` ought to be more appropriate than `Deref` here, but `&T` doesn't implement `AsRef<T>`and `Ref<T>` implements neither, so `Deref` is all we have.